# Binary search tree remove with reference to parents

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

First off, this is a school assignment, so there. I wouldn't be posting if it weren't for the fact that I'm really hurting for help.

Now we have this binary search tree we are supposed to implement. Basically, this class below is complete, I am given to understand.

```
    public class BinarySearchTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    BinarySearchTreeNode<T> _root;

    public BinarySearchTreeNode<T> Root
    {
        get { return _root; }
    }

    public BinarySearchTree()
    {

    }

    public BinarySearchTree(BinarySearchTreeNode<T> root)
    {
        _root = root;
    }

    public void Insert(T value)
    {
        if (_root != null)
            _root.Insert(value);
        else
            _root = new BinarySearchTreeNode<T>(value);
    }

    public void Remove(T value)
    {
        if (_root == null)
            return;

        if (_root.LeftChild != null || _root.RightChild != null)
        {
            _root.Remove(value);
        }
        else if (_root.Value.CompareTo(value) == 0)
        {
            _root = null;
        }
    }

    public bool Find(T value)
    {
        if (_root != null)
            return _root.Find(value);
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

And here the class I am supposed to implement, or at least as far as I have gotten.

```
public class BinarySearchTreeNode<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private T _value;
    public T Value 
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    public BinarySearchTreeNode<T> LeftChild
    {
        get { return _leftChild; }
        set { _leftChild = value; }
    }
    private BinarySearchTreeNode<T> _leftChild, _parent, _rightChild;

    public BinarySearchTreeNode<T> RightChild
    {
        get { return _rightChild; }
        set { _rightChild = value; }
    }

    public BinarySearchTreeNode<T> Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set { _parent = value; }
    }

    public BinarySearchTreeNode(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        Parent = this;
    }

    public void Insert(T value)
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(Parent.Value) < 0)
        {

            if (LeftChild != null)
            {
                LeftChild.Insert(value);
             }
            else
            {
                LeftChild = new BinarySearchTreeNode<T>(value);
                LeftChild.Parent = this;
            }

        }
        else if (Value.CompareTo(Parent.Value) >= 0)
        {
            if (RightChild != null)
                RightChild.Insert(value);
            else{
                RightChild = new BinarySearchTreeNode<T>(value); 
                Righthild.Parent = this;
                }
        }

    }

    public void Remove(T value) 
    {



        if (LeftChild != null)
            if (value.CompareTo(Parent.Value) < 0)
                    LeftChild.Remove(value);

            else if (RightChild != null)
                if (value.CompareTo(Parent.Value) >= 0)
                    RightChild.Remove(value);
    }


    public bool Find(T value)
    {
        if (value.Equals(Parent.Value)) 
            return true;

        else if (value.CompareTo(Parent.Value) < 0)
        {
            if (LeftChild != null)
                return LeftChild.Find(value);
        }
        else if (value.CompareTo(Parent.Value) > 0)
        {
            if (RightChild != null)
                return RightChild.Find(value);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

The issue is that I can't quite seem to get my head around just how I am supposed to properly implement remove, so that I can remove a node simply by pointing towards the parents, for instance. Any help or hints is appreciated.

Edit(!)

So I got almost everything in order, baring one thing which is case 2 for the remove method.

```
            //Case 2: If node has only one child, copy the value of the child to your node, and assign LeftChild or RightChild to null (as is the case)   
            if (RightChild != null && LeftChild == null)
            {
                if (value.CompareTo(this.Parent._value) > 0)
                {
                    Parent.RightChild = RightChild;
                    RightChild = null;
                }
            }
            if (RightChild == null && LeftChild != null)
            {
                if (value.CompareTo(Parent._value) < 0)
                {
                Parent.LeftChild = LeftChild;
                LeftChild = null;
                }
            }
```

Basically, I am completely unable to replace the original node. If I have have 
4 - 3 - 2 ( preorder ) and I want to remove 3 then I can do that and get 4 - 2.
However, if I want to remove 4 , it won't do anything, though it only got one child. I am think thats because it doesn't have a parent, but I am unsure of how to get around that. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? How did that fail? What exactly don't you understand in the description you're using?

Comment: I need to figure out how to replace the node that doesn't have a parent.

Answer (score 0):

[Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion)

> There are three possible cases to consider:
>   Deleting a leaf (node with no children): Deleting a leaf is easy, as we can simply remove it from the tree.
>   Deleting a node with one child: Remove the node and replace it with its child.
>   Deleting a node with two children: Call the node to be deleted N. Do not delete N. Instead, choose either its in-order successor node or its in-order predecessor node, R. Replace the value of N with the value of R, then delete R.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add one more condition to your remove method whose pseudo-code is:

```
    if (value.CompareTo(Parent.Value) == 0){
        //Case 1: If node has no children, then make Parent = null
        // Case 2: If node has only one child, copy the value of the child to your node, and assign LeftChild or RightChild to null (as is the case)
        //Case 3: Find the in-order successor, copy its value to the current node and delete the in-order successor.

    }
```

Comment: I have tried this, basically, but it seem like declaring Parent = null makes me unable to work with parent anymore, so when I try to use it again the program will freeze and say that parent is null.

Comment: Parent should be assigned to null only if the node has no LeftChild or RightChild. That would be Case 1.

Comment: Got most of that now, except in case 2 where the node I want to replace is the first node...